# Vue.js this.lowerCanvasEl.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs

I am using the fabric library to make a whiteboard but it has the following error:

> TypeError: this.lowerCanvasEl.getContext is not a function

I saw some possible solutions where it indicates that canvas should be in a `<canvas>` component but in my code it is as follows:

```
 <template>
  <div class="canvas-box">
    <div class="center">
      <canvas height="600px" ref="main" width="900px" id="main"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { fabric } from "fabric";
export default {
  mounted() {
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("main"); 
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think it should be `new fabric.Canvas(this.$refs.main)`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Karl-AndréGagnon it works!